# Asking for SMTP Authentication in mail server PHPMailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to use PHPmailer to send mails. My webhost has said if the mail is relayed through their datacenter, no credentials are required. This is my code:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPDebug    = 2;
$mail->isSMTP();

$mail->Host         = 'smtpgateway.webhost.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth     = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure   = false;
$mail->port         = 25;
$mail->setFrom('info@mydomain.com', 'Test');
$mail->Subject      = $email_subject;
$mail->Body         = $email_body;
$mail->addAddress($email, $name);
$mail->isHTML(true);
if($mail->send())
{
    echo "Success";
}
```

But I get this error when trying to send email:

> 2018-08-21 10:07:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM: info@mydomain.com
>
> 2018-08-21 10:07:03 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 OK
>
> 2018-08-21 10:07:03 CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:test@example.com
>
> 2018-08-21 10:07:03 SERVER -> CLIENT: 550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client. (mydomain.com)550-[10.100.15.115]:41032 is not permitted to relay through this server without550 authentication.
>
> 2018-08-21 10:07:03 SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client (mydomain.com)550-[10.100.15.115]:41032 is not permitted to relay through this server without550 authentication.

Comment: ??? `$mail->SMTPAuth     = false;` ???

Comment: Don't use any of the SMTP bits

Comment: @RiggsFolly Webhost said no authentication is needed.

Comment: Then why is this `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` set? Try it with `$mail->SMTPAuth = true;` and a userid and pasword, see if the error message changes

Comment: @RiggsFolly SMTP was failing to connect. My website does not have SSL certificate, so I read connection failure maybe due to that. I added that line and it started working. I cannot create mail accounts with this host, so I do not want to use SMTPAuth = true.

Comment: You dont need an SSL certificate for this

Comment: Okay I removed that line, I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

If this was purely about authentication, I would expect that first `MAIL FROM` command to fail. The "relaying" message should be read like this:

```
(mydomain.com) is not permitted to relay through this server without authentication.
```

This suggests that this server doesn't host email for either the FROM or TO domains, i.e. it's relaying, and relaying without authentication makes it an open relay, which is a bad thing (unless it's inaccessible from outside). I would guess that you may need to use a different from domain for it to work without authentication, and look earlier in the SMTP transcript (at the response to `EHLO`), which will show whether the server actually support authentication or not.

SMTP is nearly always preferable to using the PHP mail() function; mail() is slower and less safe. All a sendmail binary does is open a synchronous SMTP connection to localhost anyway, so you're skipping an unnecessary process by doing it directly. Neither route makes any guarantees about speed of delivery - SMTP is a store-and-forward protocol, and operations can be extremely slow, which is why you want to hand off the job to a local mail server.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Here is my code and the response I received: pastebin.com/AYhwygg4 
It seems authentication is supported? I tried changing the from address to a random gmail one (without authentication) and it gave me the same response. 

My webhost provided me with an SMTP gateway (smtpgateway.myhost.com) and said it's not a mailserver. My preference is to use SMTP for the safety reasons I've read about it.

Comment: Sounds like your host is clueless. An SMTP gateway *is* a mail server. If they require auth, get support from them about it. Not really anything we can do from here.

Comment: LOL thanks for clearing it up. I was extremely confused when they said it. So from the debug log, it is clear they require auth, I guess I'll ask them about it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: My webhost got back to me. They are saying they faced no issues sending mails from their server. They have sent me a email to my outlook domain as proof. I'm still stuck with this code: https://pastebin.com/raw/9nKzTWkB and the same 'Turn on authentication in your client' error :|

Comment: Try using the From address they used.

Comment: They used a dummy mail from my domain (that does not actually exist). (info@mydomain.com)

Comment: My domain does not have SSL. Does this somehow cause the problem? When I comment out the SMTPOptions and SMTPSecure options, I get 'Could not connect to host' error -> https://pastebin.com/raw/6CUPpGbR

Comment: Just to clarify, they did use the mail I tried used (info@mydomain.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try without any of the SMTP details as you potentially don't need to use SMTP from what your host has said.

```
$mail->setFrom('info@mydomain.com', 'Test');
$mail->Subject      = $email_subject;
$mail->Body         = $email_body;
$mail->addAddress($email, $name);
$mail->isHTML(true);
if($mail->send())
{
    echo "Success";
}
```

Worth a try, let me know if it doesn't work, but I'm guessing you don't need SMTP here.

Check this out, similar issue: [PHPmailer without using SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427920/phpmailer-without-using-smtp)

Comment: But this would be similar to using php's inbuilt mail function right? I'm trying to relay it through their SMTP server, without authentication.

Comment: Indeed it would, but you'd be using PHP Mailers to set it up.

Comment: You would be using your hosts to send it through though

Comment: But I'd like to use SMTP since the regular mail is taking too long to receive(Sometimes hours).

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code .make sure you have given permission in Mail account from you want to send mail.

**My Account->Sign-in & security->Allow less secure apps: OFF**

```
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = false;                                 
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.live.com';                         
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
    $mail->Username = 'mail@gmail.com';                 
    $mail->Password = 'Password';                           
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    
    $mail->setFrom($details['from'], $details['from']);
    if(is_array($details['to'])){
        foreach ($details['to'] as $key => $value) {
            $mail->addAddress($value['email'], $value['name']);
        }
    }else{
        $mail->addAddress($details['to'], isset($details['name'])?:$details['to']);
    }

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject =$details['subject'];
    $mail->Body    =$details['body'];
    $mail->send();
```