# Where to Get Started When using PHP Mail()?

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am Mostly confused where to get started to sending confirmation Emails?

I have everything setup ready to send emails (just not the mailing part, like making codes, user tracking etc)

Where can I get Started (or pointed to the right way)?

Something that may effect everything, Want to Host Everything myself (meaning **no** Google SMTP)

also, using PHP 7.4

Comment: I suggest you to use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) else exist millions code for sent mail

Comment: If you have google mail ofcourse you need :)

Comment: [PHPmailer without using SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427920/phpmailer-without-using-smtp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code in my project with [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer):

```
require_once('./phpmailer/PHPMailer.php');
require_once('./phpmailer/Exception.php');
require_once('./phpmailer/OAuth.php');
require_once('./phpmailer/SMTP.php');

$email = new PHPMailer;
$email->Host = 'YOURSMTPDOMAIN';
$email->SMTPAuth = true;
$email->Username = 'YOUREMAILDOMAIN';
$email->Password = 'YOURPASSWORDDOMAIN';
$email->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$email->Port = 465;
$email->SetFrom("YOUREMAILDOMAINFROM", "NAME");
$email->addAddress('EMAILOFCLIENT');
$email->addBCC("ANOTHERRMAIL", "NAME"); //IF YOU NEED
$email->Subject = 'SUBJECT';
$email->Body = 'BODYMAIL';
$email->AddAttachment('LINK', 'NAME.pdf');//IF YOU NEED
$email->send();
```

Comment: `$email->Host = 'YOURSMTPDOMAIN';`  = YOUR SMTP DOMAIN

Comment: You don't create SMTP, when you rent a server with email you can ask for the smtp

Comment: If you have an email for example info@youdomain.it you have SMTP

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use google smtp you can try using Mailgun. Link to get started on Mailgun -> https://www.mailgun.com/blog/sending-email-using-the-mailgun-php-api/

Else if you want to set up your own SMTP server read this article https://help.fluidreview.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002141813-How-to-Set-Up-your-SMTP-Server

Comment: @NolanO There are multiple options you can use depending on the OS, but these aren't recommended for Production use. 
Here is a reference for setting it up locally https://mailtrap.io/blog/setup-smtp-server/ 

It is recommended to use a service like Mailgun or Amazon SES